# Is it possible to set Tier Prices on Downloadable products?

Tags: tierprice, downloadable

I'm new to Magento, Im developing a digital music store, I will be selling albums. I want to sell an album at a discounted price if the customer decides to buy the whole album or all songs. Example let's say a song is $1, the album has 14 tracks, the whole album should be $10.

How may I achieve this because I'm struggling?

Is it possible to achieve functionality like this with Magento 1.7? http://www.junodownload.com/products/sven-weisemann-inner-motions/2290949-02/

Comment: You could do something like a [bundled product](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product).

Comment: may you explain further? The document says Bundled product can only made from simple product or virtual product. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I see it.
The "Album" is a separate product, with its own SKU.
So create a new product and add it as a "related product" to all album tracks. When the user see the page for a track he will see the "album" as a related product with the lower price and he could buy it.

Second approach.
Discount rule.
Create a shopping cart discount rule like this:
Conditions:

[image: conditions]

And continue with the conditions. Add one row for each track you have.

This means that if all the tracks are in the cart the rule is applied.

For Actions fill in:

```
Apply: Fixed amount discount for whole cart
Discount Amount : 4
```

So you will do a fixed discount from the whole cart, and the discount amount is the price of all track minus the price of the full album. (in your case 14 - 10 = 4).